# turning off laptop monitor, xrandr turning off all screens

Tags: xrandr, display, multi-monitor

I have a pc connected to my tv, I would like to disable the laptop monitor while it's connected.

To see all the connected monitors I run this `tail /sys/class/drm/*/status` and I get:

```
==> /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/status <==
disconnected

==> /sys/class/drm/card0-LVDS-1/status <==
connected

==> /sys/class/drm/card0-VGA-1/status <==
connected
```

Now when I run `xrandr --output LVDS-1 --off`

All screens go black, and I can't even find the command to get them on so I just restart.

I would like just to just blank the laptop monitor.

After that I would add it too boot. But that should not be a problem.

Any suggestions?

p.s - when they are on I get a duplicate setting on them.

I have an `xorg.conf` file

```
'Section "Device"
  Identifier  "Device0"
  Driver      "modesetting"
  VendorName  "INTEL Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier  "Screen0"
  Device      "Device0"
  Monitor     "VGA-1"
  DefaultDepth  24
  SubSection "Display"
    Depth       24
    Modes     "1920x1080@59.94p" "1920x1080@24p" "1920x1080@60p"
  EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
  Identifier  "VGA-1"
  HorizSync   14.0 - 70.0
  VertRefresh 24.0 - 62.0
#  Option      "DPMS" "true"
  Modeline    "1920x1080@24p"     74.230 1920 2560 2604 2752 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
  Modeline    "1920x1080@50p"    148.500 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
  Modeline    "1920x1080@59.94p" 148.352 1920 1960 2016 2200 1080 1082 1088 1125 +hsync +vsync
  Modeline    "1920x1080@60p"    148.500 1920 2008 2056 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
  # fixes tearing
  Option      "Composite"           "Disable"
EndSection
```

Comment: What if you would first switch to a dual-screen mode as a workaround?

Comment: nothing is working. i tired ` xrandr --auto --output VGA-1 --mode 1920x1080@60p --right-of LVDS-1` but the tv goes blank and the laptop remains on, it's like VGA-1 doesn't know it's the TV, maybe it's because i'm using an VGA to HDMI converter?